# Convert Set to List for csv elements Java 8

Tags: java

I create the below `Set`:

```java
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("Test1,Test2");
set.add("Test3,Test4");
```

I need to convert this `Set` to a `List` by splitting of all elements separately.

Final `List` should contain four elements, i.e.

> Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4

Please clarify how to convert the `Set` to a `List` using Java 8.

I tried like this, but it returns a `List` of `List` of `String`, instead of a `List` of `String`.

```
set.stream().map(x-> Arrays.asList(x.split(","))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();        set.add("Test1,Test2")  set.add("Test3,Test4");             My Outputput should be [Test1,Test2,Test3,tes4]. Output Type  is List of String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `flatMap(...)` to convert the list of list of elements into a list of elements. Into `flatMap(...)` you need to provide a lamba or method reference to convert the elements of the stream (the lists) into a stream of elements (the actual elements of the lists).

Since here your elements in the stream are lists, you can do `Collection::stream` but if you were to keep the array (not using `Arrays.asList(...)`) you could also do `Arrays::stream`.

A final possible solution could be:

```java
set.stream().map(x -> x.split(",")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or this less efficient solution:

```java
set.stream().map(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(","))).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set.stream()
   .map(i -> Arrays.asList(i.split(",")))
   .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
   .sorted()
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `set` is a `Set` of `String`s, since you can split the items in the lambda. `String.split` returns an array of `String`s, you convert it to the `List` with `Arrays.asList`. So now you have Stream of `List<String>`s, meaning, by collecting them with `toList`, it gives you `List<List<String>>`. So before collecting the items, you need to call `flatMap(list -> list.stream())` so it becomes Stream of Strings

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider a simpler approach?

```
HashSet<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String string : mySet) {
  String[] strings = string.split(",");
  myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));
}
```

This is still *using Java 8*.

Comment: in which line? :) This code does not require Java 8 to run